# Multipart file uploading using meteor restivus

Tags: node.js, meteor, file-upload, multipartform-data, restivus

I am using Meteor-Restivus for exposing API Endpoints.

https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus/

But here I am unable to upload Multipart File.
What I have tried so far is:

```
Api.addRoute('questions/:question/photo', {authRequired: true}, {
        post: function () {
            var uploadedFile = new FS.File(this.request.files.photo.path);
            var insertedFile =  Photos.insert(uploadedFile, function (err, fileObj) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(fileObj.size()+" "+fileObj.name()+" "+fileObj.extension());
                }
            });

            return {
                status: "success",
                data: insertedFile._id
            }
        }
    }
);
```

But it says photo is undefined.

I am posting payload like this:

[image]

Comment: Is there any entry under `this.request` like in the query, header, data or body?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I am sending photo in multipart formdata

Comment: @Jankapunkt please check my updated question

Comment: I can't find anything about `this.request.files` in the restivus documentation. What makes you think that your files will show up there? Are you perhaps missing some middle-ware?

Comment: Nope I am not missing any middleware I guess.. so far I searched. Problem is that my whole api is based on this plugin and now I am stuck at file upload. Cant go with base64 since my files are huge